# how to use gitlab variable value inside config file of c#

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have declared variable in gitlab at project level,I want to use  value of that variable inside web.config to set value of a key .

```
<appsettings>
<add key="portno" value="${GIT_PORT}">
</appSettings>
```

Gitlab variable is GIT_PORT.
I am not able to replace actual value from variable.
Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Write a ```sh``` to replace the variable in your gitlab CICD

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Project Level Variables will be available as Environment variables in GtiLab Runner when it is running your Job. And You cannot use Environment Variable directly in the `web.config` file.

But as a workaround, you can use scripts to replace the value with CI environment variables.

Example:
assume this is your `web.config`

```
<appsettings>
<add key="portno" value="Some-Text-To_Replace">
</appSettings>
```

Then, Run this command.

`$ sed -i 's/Some-Text-To_Replace/${GIT_PORT}/g' web.config`

Hope This will work.

Comment: thank you @Prabhu Vignesh Rajagopal for your answer, But do I need to use above cmd in yml pipeline before building a project?
Where will I find the modified web config? Can you help here.

Comment: in the sed command, you can use the appropriate path. like `/path/to/web.config`